# Unable to load DLL The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I just want to use c++ function such as render.
so I made dll file from c++/clr, and I put it in the c# project directory /bin.
But it didn't work. and burst out error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Please tell me some useful advise

Answer (score 1):

1- You location isn't correct

2 - You have dependencies. Maybe in your Visual Studio 2003 you had another path within your project path. Check them to see what it is. Some folder is included you need to find which.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6793785a-ec98-4453-a62b-f1a85195ec05/

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're missing other DLLs that your C++ dll depends on.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/14dc569b-b761-4021-b3a7-559138daaf71/

Answer (score 0):

Potentially some sort of COM registration issue, to investigate further I'd recommend using [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Fusion was the name of the compiler before it was called the clr I believe), its a great tool for assembly binding failure analysis and its lead me to the root of issues on many occasions.